# CSS animation keyframes not content centered

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have the following for a button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sm-hover-ripple').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
   $content = $this.html(),
   $height = $this.css('height').replace('px', ''),
   $width = $this.css('width').replace('px', ''),
   $padding_top = $this.css('padding-top').replace('px', ''),
   $padding_left = $this.css('padding-left').replace('px', ''),
   $padding_bottom = $this.css('padding-bottom').replace('px', ''),
   $padding_right = $this.css('padding-right').replace('px', ''),
   $background = $this.css('background');

  var $html = '' +
   '<div class="sm-button-filler" style="' +
    'height:'+ $height +'px; ' +
    'width: '+ $width +'px; ' +
    'margin: -'+ $padding_top +'px -'+ $padding_right +'px -'+ $padding_bottom +'px -'+ $padding_left +'px' +
   '">' +
    '<div class="sm-circle-hover" style="' +
     'line-height: '+ ($height / 100) * 150 +'px; ' +
     'background: '+ $background +'; ' +
     'height: '+ ($height / 100) * 150 +'px;  ' +
                    'width:'+ ($width - 10 ) +'px; ' + 
     'border-radius: '+ $height +'px; ' +
     'margin: -'+ ((($height / 100) * 150) - $height) / 2 +'px 0 0 0;' +
     'animation:pulse-width 3000ms infinite}' +
     '@keyframes pulse-width{0%{width:'+ $width +'px}25%{width: '+ ($width - 10) +'px}50%{width: '+ ($width - 5) +'px}75%{width: '+ ($width - 10) +'px}100%{width:'+ $width +'px}}' +
    '">' +
     ''+ $content +'' +
    '</div>' +
   '</div>';

  $this.html('<div class="sm-button-filler" style="height:'+ $height +'px; width: '+ $width +'px; margin: -'+ $padding_top +'px -'+ $padding_right +'px -'+ $padding_bottom +'px -'+ $padding_left +'px"><div class="sm-circle-hover" style="line-height: '+ ($height / 100) * 150 +'px; background: '+ $background +'; height: '+ ($height / 100) * 150 +'px;  width: '+ ($width - 10) +'px; -webkit-border-radius: '+ $height +'px; -moz-border-radius: '+ $height +'px;-ms-border-radius:'+ $height +'px; -o-border-radius: '+ $height +'px; border-radius: '+ $height +'px; margin: -'+ ((($height / 100) * 150) - $height) / 2 +'px 0 0 0;">'+ $content +'</div></div>');
 },
 function() {
  var $this = $(this),
   $content = $this.find('.sm-circle-hover').html();

  $this.html($content);
 });
});
```

```css
.sm-raised-button {
  color: #fff;
  background:#2196F3;
  border: none;
  min-width: 64p;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.sm-button-filler {
  background: rgba(00, 00,00, .12);
  padding: 0 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: padding 300ms ease-in-out;
  animation: pulse-padding 3000ms infinite;
  @-keyframes pulse-padding {
    0% {
      padding: 0 0px;
    }
    25% {
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
    50% {
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    75% {
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
    100% {
      padding: 0 0px;
    }
  }
}

.sm-circle-hover {
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sm-raised-button sm-hover-ripple">Hover ripple</button>
```

I left out all of the other browser prefixes but I do have them. I don't know why the animation doesn't work in here tough it should work when you use it.

Below are a few images of what is going on:

[image: Normal][image: Hover animation][image: Hover animation]

What I was hoping to get is similar to [example](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) (Under behaviour is a short video. It's the focus example).

The problem is that when ever I hover over the button the animation starts and works but it's not keeping the content inside centered it's moving from side to side. I hope some can help me to get the content remaining in the centre.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow this looks really complicated for a simple effect. Why not simply do almost everything is `CSS`, with your link being an `a` element and the expanding circle being, for example, an `after` or `background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml)`?

Comment: check this demo here -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxEBvb

Comment: @Tasos it isn't the behaviour I'm looking for

Comment: @SuperDJ Please make clear what you are looking for in that case, as two people have given you suggestions and all we get back is `not what im looking for` - I don't know how you expect us to understand what you are looking for in that case.

Comment: So you are saying that the posted answer and link are irrelevant because they are tied to a different event? My answer below will solve your padding problem and you only need to tie it together with some classes and easy class switching in Javascript. _The issue is solved_, the _implementation_ is still up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something that worked for me. Had to use `:before` and `:after` to get the result I wanted

```css
.sm-hover-ripple {
 z-index: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.sm-hover-ripple:hover:after
  animation: beat 3s ease-in-out infinite;

  @-keyframes beat {
    0%, 50%, 100% {
      transform:scale(1) translateZ(0);
    }
    25%, 75% {
      transform: scale(.95) translateZ(0);
    }
}

.sm-hover-ripple:before {
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, .12);
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  margin: 0px -50%;
}

.sm-hover-ripple:after {
  content: "";
  width: 90%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 85%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -45%;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0) translateZ(0));
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.sm-raised-button {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  min-width: 64px;
  height:36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="sm-raised-button sm-hover-ripple">Hover ripple</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why this is so overly complicated when you can do almost *all* of this using plain old `CSS`:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 2 2"><circle fill="red" cx="1" cy="1" r="1" /></svg>') no-repeat 50% 50% orange;
  background-size: 0 0;
  transition: background-size .5s, background-color .7s;
  padding: 30px;
}
a:hover {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">TestButton</a>
```

When the animation is simplified as such, centring becomes simply a matter of using some simply CSS.

Comment: Not the behaviour I'm looking for

Comment: @SuperDJ What behaviour _are_ you looking for then because it is not at all clear from the question and my implementation is not dissimilar from the example you gave in the Material Design Docs. And if you mean 'it needs a focus, disabled and pressed style', then take the above as a way to implement it and replace your JS with a class switcher.